# Managing the experiment loop - experiment organization tool

Tags: machine-learning, experiment-design, software

Here is loop of actions I do very often in my machine learning research:

1. Run an experiment with a certain configuration (a certain classifier with certain settings, etc.).
2. Look at the log file. Try to think what configuration to change in order to improve the results.
3. Rename the log file of the experiment, so that I remember what configuration it came from. For example, from "experiment.log" to "experiment.bayesian.log" or "experiment.decisiontree.log".
4. Change the configuration and return to step 1.

This loop has many technical actions, and many opportunities to make a mistake. For example: I renamed the log, but didn't include one of the configuration params because I thought it is not significant. Then the results proved that it is significant, and I have to go over all the logs and remane them. For example, rename "experiment.bayesian.withoutboosting.log", and the new log file to "experiment.bayesian.withboosting.log"

So, I wonder if there is a system that automates this process?

Preferrably, I am looking for a generic tool, that does not depend on the programming language I use for my classifiers. Maybe a shell script, that changes a configuration file, runs a program, extracts the results from the log, and keeps them in a table.

Do you know of anything like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer from stackoverflow. It is for the R programming language, but I think some of the ideas in the post may be relevant and helpful.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437213/strategies-for-repeating-large-chunk-of-analysis/6550914#6550914

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979609/automatic-documentation-of-datasets

Update:
I made a short script based on the answer on stackoverflow:
https://github.com/kiribatu/Kiribatu-R-Toolkit/blob/master/docs/parameter_configuration.md

This script creates a parameter list and export it to external JSON file so it can be easily imported if you need to repeat the experiment. If you need a different configuration, just create another parameter list or copy the former JSON file and change that. Anyway, you can keep a better track of your experiments.